# Trying to Translate APK - Language to be translated can't be found in string.xml

Tags: android, xml, string, apk

So Im trying to translate a Japanese game into English and I was told to go to the res/values/strings.xml to find all the stuff I would need to translate. But here's the problem. The strings.xml doesn't contain any of the Japanese text im trying to translate.  In fact, all it has in it is stuff about Google play services which is already in English.

The Flowing code is from:
**..\signed_com.bandainamcogames.saocr-13\res\values\strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="store_picture_title">Save image</string>
    <string name="store_picture_message">Allow Ad to store image in Picture gallery?</string>
    <string name="accept">Accept</string>
    <string name="decline">Decline</string>
    <string name="create_calendar_title">Create calendar event</string>
    <string name="create_calendar_message">Allow Ad to create a calendar event?</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_notification_ticker">Google Play services     error</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_notification_needs_installation_title">An application requires installation of Google Play services.</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_notification_needs_update_title">An application requires an update for Google Play services.</string>
    <string name="common_android_wear_notification_needs_update_text">An application requires an update to the Android Wear app.</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_needs_enabling_title">An application requires Google Play services to be enabled.</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_error_notification_requested_by_msg">Requested by %1$s</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_install_title">Get Google Play services</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_install_text_phone">"This app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone."</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_install_text_tablet">"This app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your tablet."</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_install_button">Get Google Play services</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_enable_title">Enable Google Play services</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_enable_text">"This app won't work unless you enable Google Play services."</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_enable_button">Enable Google Play services</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_update_title">Update Google Play services</string>
    <string name="common_android_wear_update_title">Update Android Wear</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_update_text">"This app won't run unless you update Google Play services."</string>
    <string name="common_android_wear_update_text">"This app won't run unless you update the Android Wear app."</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_network_error_title">Network Error</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_network_error_text">A data connection is required to connect to Google Play services.</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_title">Invalid Account</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text">The specified account does not exist on this device. Please choose a different account.</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_unknown_issue">Unknown issue with Google Play services.</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_title">Google Play services</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_text">Google Play services, which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device. Please contact the manufacturer for assistance.</string>
    <string name="common_google_play_services_update_button">Update</string>
    <string name="common_signin_button_text">Sign in</string>
    <string name="common_signin_button_text_long">Sign in with Google</string>
    <string name="common_open_on_phone">Open on phone</string>
    <string name="wallet_buy_button_place_holder">Buy with Google</string>
    <string name="app_name">SAOｺｰﾄﾞﾚｼﾞｽﾀ</string>
    <string name="app_id">660182004897</string>
</resources>
```

It's strange because the game does indeed have Japanese lettering in it shown here: 
[Picture #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNoTX.jpg)
I have looked everywhere in the files to find some kind of language file or something to do with japanese but I cant seem to find it.


I'll upload the decomplied apk here: 
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vg1kqjmcvj43ccr/signed_com.bandainamcogames.saocr-13.zip?dl=0%22]%20Dropbox)

Any help?

Comment: this error depends on adt version. if you use the latest one, it does not give error(android developers fixed this obvious logic bug). but, if you use older version, you need to add translatable="false" to all entries of string elements for your texts in your string.xml. older adt forces you translate all strings to all languages

Comment: I was actually using the latest version of apktool to decompile it into a folder on my desktop.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by adding the translatable = "false" part. And if your talking about android studio, I downloaded the latest version a couple of hours ago. If you could explain a little more that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: sorry, I thought something else. but, it seems they might use some static image (less likely), or use strings in the code or xml. are you sure they are using strings.xml ? it is just a implementation of localisation, but it is not only way to to this. it would be good to take a look in java (smali) files and try to find this japanese text inside of them

Comment: I'm positive. And yes there are a ton of smali files, I went through most of them not too long ago only to find random code. I included a drop box link to my decompiled apk if you would be so kind to take a look as I take another peak at the smali folder.